# What color was the most recent common ancestor of all swans?

Tags: evolution

Was the most recent common ancestor of all swans black, or white, or some other color? How do we know, and how certain can we be?

Comment: Reptiles are thought to be the common ancestors of birds. Their skin color is not known, as that does not appear in the fossil record.

Comment: Your comment made me realise I'd phrased the question imprecisely. I've edited it to put in the words "most recent".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the known phylogeny of Anserinae [in this paper](http://sysbio.oxfordjournals.org/content/45/4/415.full.pdf+html),

[image]

*Cygnus atratus* (the black swan) is most closely related to *Cygnus melanocoryphus* (the black-necked swan). All of the other swans in the genus *Cygnus* are white, or close to white.

Therefore, it is reasonable to assume via [maximum parsimony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_parsimony_%28phylogenetics%29) and [maximum likelihood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood) that the two genera evolved their blackness from a white ancestor, and not that all of the swans independently turned white from a black ancestor.